# Закольцованность связей в БД

Tags: sql, база-данных

В проекте есть 2 сущности:
Car - автомобиль
Block - блок, который установлен на автомобиль.
Блок, может переустанавливаться с одного автомобиля на другой. В базе необходимо хранить историю, какой блок на каком автомобиле стоял.

Мое видинее реализации следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Коллега утверждает что здесь закольцованность, и связи "Block => Car" необходимо убрать и необходимо получать эту связь выборкой из History, проводя анализ что блок установлен и не был снят.

Я предполагаю что с моем случае закольцованности связей нет и закольцованность представляет собой немного другое.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если говорить о том, что с вашим решением не так, то это денормализованность, поскольку связь Блок-Автомобиль дублируется в двух таблицах. На такие жертвы иногда идут для повышения производительность. Я бы порекомендовал сначала сделать как надо, а если действительно возникнут проблемы с производительностью, тогда денормализовать. Закольцованность это наверное циклические внешние ключи имеются в виду. Для связи 1-0..1 это вообще обычная практика. Но у вас по моему и того нет.

Comment: По моему скромному мнению здесь всё в порядке

Answer (score 3):

Проблема тут не столько в кольце, сколько в избыточности данных в схеме - возможна ситуация, когда текущее состояние и история противоречат друг другу. Обычно лучше отдавать предпочтение схемам, которые являются самосогласованными.

Так, в вашем примере, можно было бы хранить в истории не операции - а временные отрезки существования связи автомобиля и блока.

Иными словами, для каждой записи истории надо хранить дату установки и дату снятия (вместо даты можно хранить просто автоинкрементное значение). Если дата снятия не установлена - блок стоит.

Если на такую таблицу повесить фильтрованные индексы, который включают только записи где дата снятия блока не проставлена - то получить текущее состояние можно будет столь же быстро, как и из основной таблицы - а значит, дублирующая связь становится не нужна.

Также можно будет довольно просто получить блоки, установленные в любом автомобиле в любой момент времени (но тут уже без сканирования истории будет не обойтись).

Кстати, при помощи уникального фильтрованного индекса можно заставить сервер проверять что каждый блок может быть установлен только на одном автомобиле в настоящее время.

Answer (score 0):

Вы правы, здесь нет кольца. Направление стрелок все решает.

Говоря о решение вашего коллеги - так будет красивее. Но есть одно но: если в вашем приложении будет частое обращение к выборке блоков авто, то ваш вариант более оптимален, т.к он не будет проводить вычисления реально стоящего сейчас блока, он просто выберет необходимые данные из таблицы `Car` и все. Но в данном случае бремя ответственности за своевременное обновление данных ложатся на вас, т.е при обновлении `Car`, вы тут же обязаны обновить значения `HistoryCarBlock` таблицы.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю смысл вашей схемы, сущность Block является дочерней по отношению к Car, поэтому вам в таблице Block нужно хранить признак CarId - на какой машине установлен блок.
При этом поле должно быть nullable, если существует возможность иметь блок, который не установлен ни на одной машине (лежит на складе), можно добавить уникальный ключ на CarID, если на машине может быть установлен только один блок (или уникальный ключ на связку CarID - BlockType, если на машину могут быть установлено несколько блоков разных типов, например).

Тогда таблица BlockHistory будет почти полным аналогом Block, с добавлением времени установки и времени снятия, например, или, как у вас, с добавлением типа действия (Установка/Снятие).

Comment: Я это не описал. Время операции присутствует.

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы храните историю, то в таблице HistoryCarBlock обязан присутствовать штамп времени операции. А если он присутствует, то одна из связей (Car->HistoryCarBlock 
 или Block->HistoryCarBlock, причём, что забавно, любая из них) становится лишней и может быть смело удалена. Более того - должна быть удалена, потому как если обе связи останутся, можно запросто получить (шаловливые ручки никто не отменял) несогласованные данные.